# Помогите с реализацией строковых функций в flat assembler.Поиск подстроки входящей в обратном порядке в строку и вывод ее позиции на консоль

Tags: fasm

````
entry start
 
include 'A:\Assembler\include\win32a.inc'
 
section '.idata' import data readable
library kernel, 'kernel32.dll', \
       ` msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'
import kernel, \
      ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
import msvcrt, \
       printf, 'printf', \
       gets,'gets',\
       strlen,'strlen', \
       getchar, '_fgetchar', \
       scanf,'scanf'
section '.data' data readable writeable     

MESSAGE db "Enter string %d",13,10,0
RESULT_1 db "Contains from %d",13,10,0
RESULT_2 db "Doesn't contain",13,10,0
BUF_STR_1 db 250 dup(0)
BUF_STR_2 db 250 dup(0)
LEN_1 dd 0
LEN_2 dd 0
POS dd 0
LEN_SUB dd 0
 
section '.code' code readable executable     
 
start:                                       
 
    ccall [printf], MESSAGE, dword 1
    ccall [gets], BUF_STR_1
    ccall [printf], MESSAGE, dword 2
    ccall [gets], BUF_STR_2 
    ccall [strlen], BUF_STR_1
    mov [LEN_1], eax
    ccall [strlen], BUF_STR_2
    mov [LEN_2], eax
    mov ecx, 0
    mov esi, BUF_STR_2
get_substring_length:
    lodsb            
    or al, al        
    jz end_substring_length  
    inc ecx          
    jmp get_substring_length 
end_substring_length:
    mov [LEN_SUB], ecx  
    mov edi, BUF_STR_1 
search_substring:
    mov eax, [LEN_1]  
    dec eax          
    std              
    mov esi, BUF_STR_2  
    mov ecx, [LEN_SUB] 
    repne scasb     
    jne substring_not_found  
    mov ebx, [LEN_SUB] 
    add eax, ebx       
    mov [POS], eax    
    jmp substring_found  
substring_not_found:
    mov [POS], -1     
substring_found:
    cmp [POS], -1      
    jne substring_found_output
    ccall [printf], RESULT_2  
    jmp end_program
substring_found_output:
    ccall [printf], RESULT_1, [POS]  
end_program:
    ccall [getchar]
    ccall [ExitProcess], 0
```[![что получается в итоге][1]][1]  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hETZ.png
````